# Will if / else if / else become an expressions in typescript / javascript at some point?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I really like this feature in Kotlin:

> In Kotlin, if is an expression, i.e. it returns a value.
>
> ```
> // As expression 
> val max = if (a > b) a else b
> ```

(from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html)

Is this also planned for typescript / javascript?

**Update:**

In reply to the ternary operator suggestions, of course I also mean cases with else if:

```
val bla = if ( 5 == 6) {
    7
} else if (5 == 7) {
    8
} else {
    9
}

println(bla) // prints 9
```

Comment: um ternary operator? `var max = a > b ? a : b`

Comment: `var max = a > b ? a : b;`

Comment: In this case, yes, ternary. I think what he means is "are there plans to make `if` an expression that returns a value". `if` can have multiple clauses, which is clumsy with ternary.

Comment: Who's to say for sure? I'm not an author of the ECMAScript spec but: probably not, it would break the syntax rules already in place that separate single lines from multiple lines (because JS allows you to write everything in one line separating evaluations by a `;`)

Comment: `var bla = 5==6? 7 : 5==7? 8 : 9`

Comment: @Aleksey well i don't find this very comprehensible

Comment: @bersling just write it down in multiline form and you'll see that `?` replaces `if` and `:` - `else`

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10841

Comment: If/else as a statement instead of an expression is a pain point you will absolutely feel once you've written in more thoughtfully-designed languages. The ternary operator is not a substitute for an expression if/else: it doesn't support multiple conditions (without nesting) and is difficult to read and indent correctly when it spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this also planned for typescript / javascript?

No. Statements vs. *Only* Expressions is a pretty hard fork in language design and will not change without breaking existing code so *will not happen*.

Simple example:

```
var foo = 123;
function inc(){
  foo = foo + 1;
}
```

Going down the expression route would change the return of this function from `undefined` to `foo` which can drastically break existing code for more complex functions.

Comment: Your example could be updated to be more in tune with the question, which concerns `if  else` block statements. AFAIK, the parser currently disallows `let x = if ...`, so it would seem at first glance that the backwards compatibility argument doesn't apply 100%? The addition of  `"use strict"` is another example where rules have changed very subtly in the past. Also AST-wise `foo = foo + 1`, and `foo = foo + 1;` are different. I'm not sure it's as clear cut as you make it to be, but I could be convinced with a list of proposals that have been rejected. It's a big change for sure.

Answer (score 2):

It already exists [Ternary Conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/conditional-ternary-operator-decrement-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

There's the ["do expressions" proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) for ECMAScript, which would enable us to write:

```
let x = do {
  if (foo()) {
    let tmp = f();
    tmp * tmp + 1
  }
  else if (bar()) { g() }
  else { h() }
};
```

...which is much less awkward than the ternaries. Unfortunately after 6 years it's still an early-stage proposal, and [as such](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70561026/1026), will not be [implemented in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13156) until it reaches Stage 3 in the JS standardization process.

Comment: Honestly that seems a lot more awkward that ternaries. Looks like a do while with non-returning where something like C#'s switch expressions, or Rust's match would be a lot clearer :v

Comment: @JaDa the syntax is imperfect (the other commenters explained why), but definitely less awkward than ternaries. I amended the example to include a temporary variable inside one of branches. Imagine doing that with ternaries (I just did before deciding to look up the do expressions.)

Comment: Except now your example is wrong because you intentionally made it awkward. If foo it will return undefined, and otherwise what g and h returns. No reason why you would want to do that and no reason why it couldn't live inside f. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFASkQbwLAChGIQIDOUiATgKbEgA2ZAvIgIwDceBtlZUlAtgAdETKjXrt8iXoMQAqKfyEBqFhIJUoIcklF0oEgL548oSLASIA5uiwcK3LUgBMh47lPR4SABY2ckjUdEAGZXXBNwTwtgODg-O0DtKXIQSjCIsy9EACMAQ3J4gIck4FzaYjS8I3CarjIAD2FEOxi4jAB+ZBsALjs8go6rHrtfNFYgA

Comment: @JaDa I'm not sure why you think it would return `undefined` in the first branch. In my understanding it would return the value of the last expression (`tmp * tmp + 1`). Re: "no reason", you're not really saying that every multi-statement block should/must be refactored into a standalone function, are you?:)