# Can early-stage proposals be used in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I want to use a proposal [do-expressions](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions) in a TypeScript codebase.

Is it possible and how should I configure TypeScript if it is?

Comment: Generally speaking proposals need to be at Stage 3 before TS will implement them; do-expressions is still at Stage 1 so there’s almost no chance of this happening.  See [ms/TS#13156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13156) for a canonical answer.  I can write this up when I get off mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13156](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13156) for an authoritative answer.

As of 2022/01/02, TypeScript does not support the [do-expressions proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions).  That proposal is currently at Stage 1 of [the TC39 Process](https://tc39.es/process-document/), but TypeScript generally waits until proposals reach Stage 3 before implementing them.  The relevant feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#13156 is therefore marked as "waiting for TC39".